Session not showing in devTools despite being saved in mongo and logged in middleware
Trying to set a session in a react app with the use of express and express-session and all the MongoDB session tools.
I've tried many approaches even moving the way how I'm setting the middleware for sessions to see if I can see the session in the devTools. Although I can see that the session is saved in MongoDb and the console.log(req.session) displays the cookie, I can't see it in the devTools. Below my code:
App.js server:

dbConnection.on(
  "error",
  console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:")
);
dbConnection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});

const mongoStore = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: databaseUrl,
  collection: "sessions",
});

// CORS configuration
app.use(cors());
// cookie session setup

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false, // save session when it changes.
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
    },
    store: mongoStore,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // x-www-form-urlencoded <form>
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // application/json
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.session);
  next();
});

app.use("/feed", feedRoutes);
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);

// error middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const status = err.statusCode || 500;
  const message = err.message;
  res.status(status).json({ message: message });
});

mongoose
  .connect(databaseUrl)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(8080, () => {
      console.log("connected to mongoose");
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.dir;
    console.log(err);
  });

I'm setting the session to saveUninitialized but it doesn't work when I load the react app page. Is there something off in my middleware setup? or is there any additional work I need to do in the frontend for this to work. I don't think so...?

Hi, Can you please share the General, Request and Response headers in Raw format in this case. As you know this is available in Chrome/Network/Headers section. Sample output will be as GET /access HTTP/1.1
Accept: /
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd ... HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
....
